# Running a Django Celery Beat taks depending on some Model date field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

Is there some way to relate Django celery tasks for each record saved in the database?
For example, if I want to each user receives an email depending on what date the user wants it.

Maybe I wrong thinking the solution to problems like this is solve by Django celery, can any help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the celery task in database. Use this link  https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Using database backed celery task you can start stop delete the task depending on your requirement.